# Problem resolving "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm making a quiz and I keep encountering the following errors "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" or "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')" until (reading'3')...
I understand what the error theoretically is about, but I can't figure what's wrong about my code.

I do not use checkbox type inputs, I use simple `<button>` which have an id, so in order to know wether a button was clicked or not I call buttonClicked() function with onclick, I also have a matrix of boolean corresponding to the buttons status (clicked or not) called status4Answers declared and initialized earlier in the script, the values of this matrix are modified in this very same function.

```
let statusQuestion1 = [false, false, false, false];
let statusQuestion5 = [false, false, false, false];
let statusQuestion6 = [false, false, false, false];
let statusQuestion7 = [false, false, false, false];

let status4Answers = [statusQuestion1, statusQuestion5, statusQuestion6, statusQuestion7];
```

The getQuestionFromId(id) function return an array of integers from the id paramter. This array corresponds to the question number and position of answer in the follow exemple I give you it returns [5, 1] for id="q5ans1" for example.

```
<div class="question" id="q5">
                    <p class="wording">Quelles de ces émotions sont les plus instructrices selon vous:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><button class="quizButton" id="q5ans1" type="button" value="joie" onclick="answerClicked(this.id)">La joie</button></li>
                        <li><button class="quizButton" id="q5ans2" type="button" value="tristesse" onclick="answerClicked(this.id)">La tristesse</button></li>
                        <li><button class="quizButton" id="q5ans3" type="button" value="regret" onclick="answerClicked(this.id)">Le regret</button></li>
                        <li><button class="quizButton" id="q5ans4" type="button" value="colere" onclick="answerClicked(this.id)">La colère</button></li>
                        
                    </ul> 
</div>
```

```
function getQuestionFromId(id){
                var serie = parseInt(id.charAt(1));
                var question = parseInt(id.charAt(5));
                
                var question = [serie, question];

                return question;
            }
```

```
function answerClicked(id){
                var button = document.getElementById(id);

                questionNumber = getQuestionFromId(id);
                

                if (questionNumber[0]== 1 || questionNumber[0] == 5 || questionNumber[0]== 6 || questionNumber[0]== 7){
                    
                    console.log(questionNumber);
                    console.log(status4Answers);

                    if (status4Answers[questionNumber[0]-1][questionNumber[1]-1] == false){
                        status4Answers[questionNumber[0]-1][questionNumber[1]-1] = true;
                        button.style.backgroundColor="#4e43ca";
                        button.style.color = "white";

                    }
                    else{
                        status4Answers[questionNumber[0]-1][questionNumber[1]-1] = false;
                        button.style.backgroundColor="white";
                        button.style.color = "#4e43ca";
                    }
                    console.log("after click4");
                    console.log(status4Answers);

                }
                else if (questionNumber[0]== 2 || questionNumber[0] == 3 || questionNumber[0]== 4 || questionNumber[0]== 8 || questionNumber[0]== 9){
                    if (status2Answers[questionNumber[0]-1][questionNumber[1]-1] == false){
                        status2Answers[questionNumber[0]-1][questionNumber[1]-1] = true;
                        button.style.backgroundColor="#4e43ca";
                        button.style.color = "white";

                    }
                    else{
                        status4Answers[questionNumber[0]-1 ][questionNumber[1]-1] = false;
                        button.style.backgroundColor="white";
                        button.style.color = "#4e43ca";
                    }
                    console.log("after click2");
                    console.log(status2Answers);
                    
                }
```

The console indicated an error on this specific line:

```
if (status4Answers[questionNumber[0]-1][questionNumber[1]-1] == false)
```

Tried to describe the problem as best as I can, your help is greatly appreciated.

Have a good day/night

Comment: `status4Answers` is never defined or assigned a value. Presumably it does not have anything at index #4 so `status4Answers[4][0]` produces your error

Comment: @Phil sry, forgot to mention its initialization I edited the question you can now see how I've done it.

Comment: Yep, so just like I said, `status4Answers[4]` is undefined since it only has 4 elements, indexes 0 to 3 (inclusive). The `4` comes from your equation `questionNumber[0]-1 === 5-1 === 4`

Comment: @Phil ok thanks now I see it, I understand how to solve it, thank you very much